# Add Join not working in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.6

I'm trying to built a really simple  model in ArcGIS 10.6 but it won't work.

I want to merge two shapefiles and then join the output-file with a .csv table. The merging works fine but the model builder won't let me join the output with the .csv

Comment: Just saying it "won't let me join the output" is a totally unhelpful statement. What is the error? What are the fields you trying to join on and their datatype, what does your model look like? You need to significantly improve your question if you want answers.

Comment: What does your model so far look like? What precisely happens when you run it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can do a join with a CSV in ModelBuilder. You are going to either convert it to a DBF or load it into a GDB